# Xamarin android application fails on https calls on some devices

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, okhttp

I am having a problem on some android devices regarding to HTTPS calls using `modernhttpclient`.

Request fails on 4.2.2 but works on 5.1.1
here is the stack.

Server certificate is trusted and given by Digicert.

```
System.out] propertyValue:true
[System.out] [CDS]rx timeout:0
[System.out] [socket][2] connection myadress.myserver.com/someiphere:443;LocalPort=54298(0)
[System.out] [CDS]blocking mode socket with zero timeout
[System.out] [CDS]connect[myadress.myserver.com/someiphere:443]
[Posix] [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.package.name :443 
[System.out] [CDS]port[54298]
[System.out] [socket][/172.20.10.8:54298] connected
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake fd=0x1eb00005 shc=0x1f600009 timeout_millis=0 client_mode=1 npn=0x0
[NativeCrypto] doing handshake ++
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback where=0x10 ret=1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 handshake start in UNKWN  before/connect initialization
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback ignored
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 SSL_connect:UNKWN  before/connect initialization
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback ignored
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 SSL_connect:23WCHA SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback ignored
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=-1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 SSL_connect:error exit in 23RSHA SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback ignored
[NativeCrypto] doing handshake -- ret=-1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=0
[NativeCrypto] sslSelect type=READ fd=72 appData=0x61c7a898 timeout_millis=0
[NativeCrypto] sslSelect READ fd=72 appData=0x61c7a898 timeout_millis=0 => 1
[NativeCrypto] doing handshake ++
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=-1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 SSL_connect:error exit in 23RSHA SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 info_callback ignored
[NativeCrypto] doing handshake -- ret=-1
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=104 sslError=5 timeout_millis=0
[NativeCrypto] Unknown error during handshake
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake unclean error => 0
[NativeCrypto] ssl=0x61c797b8 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
[NativeCrypto]  sslNotify, appData=0x61c7a898 ret=1
[NativeCrypto]  sslNotify, appData=0x61c7a898 ret=1
[System.out] [CDS]close[54298]
[System.out] close [socket][/0.0.0.0:54298]
[System.out] [CDS]rx timeout:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors for untrusted certificate (i.e. generated for different *Common Name (CN)*). Using the same server with correct CN it worked.